# SQL: fill new column based on latest/non latest timestamp for each entity row (having many rows per entity)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I have a non-unique columns ENTITY_ID and UPDATE_TIME.

I have added a third column of type Bit and called IS_LATEST.

How I can update the whole table by setting IS_LATEST=1 for latest UPDATE_TIME and IS_LATEST=0 for non-latest UPDATE_TIME for each ENTITY_ID?

Starting point:

```
ENTITY_ID  UPDATE_TIME   IS_LATEST
entity1    21-02-2019    NULL
entity1    20-02-2019    NULL
entity2    20-02-2019    NULL
```

Desired result:

```
ENTITY_ID  UPDATE_TIME   IS_LATEST
entity1    21-02-2019    1
entity1    20-02-2019    0
entity2    20-02-2019    1
```

I use MS SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
with cte as (
     select t.*, 
            max(UPDATE_TIME) over (partition by ENTITY_ID) as max_update
     from table t
)
update c
       set c.IS_LATEST = (case when c.UPDATE_TIME = max_update then 1 else 0 end)
from cte c;
```

You can also use `APPLY` :

```
update t
      set t.IS_LATEST = (case when c.UPDATE_TIME = max_update then 1 else 0 end)
from table t cross apply
     (select max(t1.UPDATE_TIME) as max_update
      from table t1
      where t1.ENTITY_ID = t.ENTITY_ID
     ) t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.IS_LATEST = (CASE WHEN b.ENTITY_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM entity_table AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT ENTITY_ID, MAX(UPDATE_TIME) AS UPDATE_TIME FROM entity_table GROUP BY ENTITY_ID
) AS b ON a.ENTITY_ID = b.ENTITY_ID AND a.UPDATE_TIME = b.UPDATE_TIME 
;
```